# Redirecting child process stdout via console screen buffer in Windows 10 C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to redirect the `stdout` of a child process in Windows. Both are console programs. I don't have the source code of the child process, so I can't force it to flush the buffer. As discussed [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection?fid=353676&select=2908948&fr=1#xx0xx) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles), for the implementation of `printf` and similar, the C runtime buffers everything except consoles and printers. So the solution is apparently to create a console screen buffer using, appropriately enough, `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`. I'm using [the approach from codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection?fid=353676&select=2908948&fr=1#xx0xx).

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
HANDLE hConsole;
const COORD origin = { 0, 0 };

// Default security descriptor. Set inheritable. 
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE; // So the child can use it

// Create and initialize screen buffer
hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       // Desired access       
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, // share mode to child processes
    &sa,                                // SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES      
    CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,            // Must be this.   
    NULL                                // Reserved. Must be NULL 
);
DWORD dwDummy;
FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, '\0', MAXLONG, origin, &dwDummy)
```

Now I direct the child's stdout to the console and start the process

```
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES; // first one prevents cursor from showing loading.
si.hStdOutput = hConsole;

//...
// Get the command line and environmental block
//...

if (! CreateProcess(
    NULL,                         // module name. 
    (char*)command_line.c_str(),  // command line
    NULL,                         // process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    NULL,                         // thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    TRUE,                         // inherit handles
    NULL,                         // creation flags
    enviros,                      // environmentBlock (enviros=NULL for testing)
    cDir,                         // working directory
    &si,                          // STARTUP_INFO object
    &pi                           // PROCESSINFO
) ){
    auto test = GetLastError();
    CloseHandle(hConsole);
    return false;
}
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Then, in a loop, I can use `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter` to grab output, as shown at the codeproject link. It looks like

```
//... some initialization

GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
DWORD count = (csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y - lastpos.Y)*lineWidth + csbi.dwCursorPosition.X - lastpos.X;
LPTSTR buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(0, count * sizeof(TCHAR));
ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, buffer, count, lastpos, &count);
DWORD dwDummy;
FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, '\0', count, lastpos, &dwDummy);

//... Now move the cursor and grab the data from `buffer`
```

On Windows 7/8.1 this works fine for all programs. **On Windows 10, some programs seem to be bypassing the supplied handles and printing directly to the parent console**, preventing me from grabbing the output as I need.

I do have an additional clue. If I force the process to create a new console window, i.e.

```
CreateProcess(NULL, (char*)command_line.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, enviros, cDir, &si, &pi)
```

but still redirect the handles in the `STARTUPINFO` object, the new console will display a single line that says `The system cannot write to the specified device`, which just happens to be the exact wording of Windows error code `ERROR_WRITE_FAULT = 29` in [the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). This happens only for those programs which aren't working as expected. Other programs, the new console is blank and they still function as expected.

My first thought is a permissions problem, but I have wide open permissions on the directories of the relevant executables.

Things I've tried

- A different computer with Windows 10
- Different versions of MS Visual C++ runtime
- Setting the working directory explicitly in `CreateProcess`
- Adding a super-permissive DACL to a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` object passed to `CreateProcess`
- Adding a super-permissive DACL to a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` object passed to `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`
- Moving everything to a newly created directory under my Windows user directory
- Running as administrator

---

**Deeper**

Thank you @PaulSanders for your suggestion.

To aid with anyone who might want to assist, I've made available [a modified version of the RTConsole code from the codeproject page](http://scico.us/files/RTConsole2.zip). It should compile in Visual Studio with just a retarget, I think. Around line 135, I've prepended a little string to the front of the output which takes the expected path. I've provided a pre-compiled version in there for convenience, as well.

One example of software that doesn't work is [EWBF miner](https://github.com/nanopool/ewbf-miner/releases). For a quick test using the code I provided above, you could run

```
RTConsole2.exe "path\to\ewbf.exe" --help
```

You'll see that the prepended flag is not present in the output.

On the other hand, with [ccminer](https://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer/releases), you'll get the expected behavior when running

```
RTConsole2.exe "path\to\ccminer.exe" --help
```

Comment: @buck Nice post, lots of detail.  _... some programs ..._ Which programs?  (One or two, at least).  If anyone wants to dig into this, they will need to know.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the suggestion. It's one I've played with a little without success, but did not list. I believe that `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer` will redirect the output of the parent's process, so effectively like calling `setStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hConsole)`. I lost the output from the parent process when I tried that.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you for your interest. I've added an edit.

Comment: @eryksun Yes. That appears to be it. Setting the parent command prompt to legacy mode gets the expected results. I'm glad it's a Windows bug and that I'm not losing my mind. If you write this up as an answer, I'll of course accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new console implementation in Windows 10 has a bug in which high-level `WriteConsole` and `WriteFile` to a non-active screen buffer instead always writes to the active screen buffer. Low-level `WriteConsoleOutput[Character]` works correctly. Using the legacy console also works. You can enable the legacy console in the properties dialog.

---

Note that a process cannot use an inherited handle for a screen buffer in the parent's console if it allocates a new console due to the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag. Trying to write to the screen-buffer file will fail because it's not bound to the caller's attached console (i.e. instance of conhost.exe).

Console files that are bound include "CON", "CONIN$", "CONOUT$", and a new screen buffer from `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`. There are also unbound input and output console files, which are set as the standard handles when allocating a new console (e.g. via `AllocConsole()`). These handles access the input buffer and active screen buffer of any attached console [*]. Note that a process can have handles for console files that are bound to multiple consoles and can switch between consoles using `AttachConsole`.

Note also that some programs open "CONOUT$" instead of writing to the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` handles, especially if they require a console instead of whatever the standard handles might be (e.g. a pipe or disk file). In this case it is not enough to set `hStdOutput` in `STARTUPINFO`. You have to temporarily make the new screen buffer active via `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`. This does not affect the caller's standard handles. It sets the active screen buffer in the attached console, which is what "CONOUT$" opens. The previous screen buffer can be restored after the child process exits, or after you know the child has already opened and written to the new screen buffer.

---

[*] In Windows 8+, these console files are implemented by the condrv.sys device driver and opened on "\Device\ConDrv". They are respectively named "Console", "CurrentIn", "CurrentOut", "ScreenBuffer", "Input", and "Output". The filename for the console connection itself is "Connect". Internally the latter is opened as the process `ConsoleHandle`, which is used implicitly by the console API in some cases (e.g. `GetConsoleWindow`, `GetConsoleCP`, and `GetConsoleTitle`).

Comment: I read the documentation (e.g. about [screen buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers)) and experiment to fill in the gaps (either undocumented behavior or just gaps in my understanding of the docs). For the latter, I use debuggers attached on the client side, the server side (conhost.exe), and the kernel (condrv.sys).